# Ember Fastboot is not working with the post request

Tags: ember.js, fastboot, ember.js-fastboot

while Accessing website in browser , i am seeing the below error..

Api is working in the browser as well as in postman but Ember fastboot is not working ... Any help should be really helpful.

FetchError: request to https://test.news.bor.doi.test/api/?format=json&type=footer&type=footer-menu failed, reason: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND test.news.bor.doi.test
at ClientRequest. (/data/webs/newsdev/frontend/node_modules/node-fetch/lib/index.js:1491:11)
at ClientRequest.emit (node:events:527:28)
at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (node:_http_client:454:9)
at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:527:28)
at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:157:8)
at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:122:3)
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21)

Comment: does that domain exist? `test.news.bor.doi.test ` ?

Answer (score 0):

Once i had the same problem , what causing it for me was the dns server is set to `localhost` , so my server was not resolving any domain name.
check `/etc/resolv.conf`  if it is `nameserver localhost`  change it to `nameserver 8.8.8.8`